# Difference between こと and と, word choices

Tags: word-choice

What's the difference between using these structures

- 行くことを決めた
- 行くと決めた
- 行くことに決めた
- 行くって決めた

They all mean "I have decided to go". So which one should I use?

Comment: I think it would be more natural to say something along the lines of "行くことにした”.

Comment: って is just a casual/colloquial variant of と.